# C++ vector<Struct> sorting not working

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm currently trying to write a function that sorts a vector of Entry items, which are defined here in my header file.

```
struct Entry{
    string word;
    int count;
};
```

Basically, each Entry has a `string` and an `int`. What I'm trying to do is sort a `vector<Entry>` by each Entry's `count` value in descending order. I've tried using `std::sort` in the .cpp file:

```
bool intcomp(const Entry &lhs, const Entry &rhs){
    return lhs.count < rhs.count;
}

void SortedByCount(std::ostream &out) const{
    std::sort(vocabulary.begin(), vocabulary.end(), intcomp);
}
```

but the compiler then spits out a huge wall of errors, like this one

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_heap.h:247:12: note:
  in instantiation of function template specialization
  'std::__push_heap<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Entry *const *,
  std::vector<Entry *, std::allocator<Entry *> > >, long, Entry *>'
  requested here
  std::__push_heap(__first, __holeIndex, __topIndex,
       ^
```

I'm very lost on what to do, so any pointers will be appreciated.

EDIT: 
The header file contains the struct for Entry and its constructor, as well as the prototype for `intcomp` and `SortedByCount(std::ostream &out) const`, while the .cpp file contains the definition of `intcomp` and `SortedByCount(std::ostream &out) const`. I get this error:

```
 reference to non-static member function must
 be called
 std::sort(vocabulary.begin(), vocabulary.end(), intcomp);
                                                 ^
```

Is it because the `intcomp()` method isn't static? Or what else could it be? Thanks again.

Comment: From the error message one can see that your `vocabulary` vector presumably stores pointers to `Entry`, i.e. `std::vector<Entry*>`

Comment: You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works just fine:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Entry {
    std::string word;
    int count;

    Entry(const std::string& s, int c) : word(s), count(c) {}
};

std::vector<Entry> vocabulary;

bool intcomp(const Entry &lhs, const Entry &rhs) {
    return lhs.count < rhs.count;
}

void sortedbycount(std::ostream &out) {
    std::sort(vocabulary.begin(), vocabulary.end(), intcomp);
}

void main()
{
    vocabulary.push_back(Entry("second", 2));
    vocabulary.push_back(Entry("firs", 1));
    vocabulary.push_back(Entry("third", 3));

    sortedbycount(std::cout);

    for (const auto& e : vocabulary)
    {
        std::cout << e.word << " " << e.count << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's odd, since I get a `reference to non-static member function must be called` error, with a little carrot pointing to the call to `intcomp` in std::sort.

Answer (score 3):

Your `vocabulary` vector contains pointers to `Entry`s, not `Entry`s themselves. Change your comparator to the following:

```cpp
bool intcomp(const Entry *lhs, const Entry *rhs){
    return lhs->count < rhs->count;
}
```

Comment: I did just what you've said, but it still spits out a wall that says `error: read-only variable is not assignable`, along with this `note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Entry *const *, std::vector<Entry *,
      std::allocator<Entry *> > > >' requested
`

Comment: If `vocabulary` is a member of the same class as `SortedByCount`, then remove `const` at the end of `SortedByCount` declaration -- const method cannot change the state of the struct. Otherwise confirm that the `vocabulary` itself is not a `const vector` (though it does not appear to be from the error messages you are pasting)

Answer (score 0):

To sort vector content using custom criteria, you can use a C++11 lambda:

```
sort(entries.begin(), entries.end(),
    [](const Entry& a, const Entry& b)
    {
        return a.Count > b.Count;
    }
);
```

Compilable source code sample follows ([**live here** on Ideone](http://ideone.com/NqkwRt)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Entry 
{
    string Word;
    int Count;

    Entry(const string& word, int count)
        : Word(word), Count(count)
    {
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<Entry> entries = {{"hello", 2}, {"world", 8}, {"hi", 20}, {"connie", 10}};

    sort(entries.begin(), entries.end(),
        [](const Entry& a, const Entry& b)
        {
            return a.Count > b.Count;
        }
    );

    for (const auto& e : entries)
    {
        cout << e.Word << ": " << e.Count << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> hi: 20
> connie: 10
> world: 8
> hello: 2
> ```